# How parsing xml from url and get attribute php

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I need parsing xml from [file to parsing](https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?exchange&coursid=3), but i can parsing only local file, how i can parsing file from url?

I use this php code

```
<?php
include '/example1.php';
$string = $xmlstr;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($xml->row->exchangerate[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
} 
?>
```

example1.php code

```
<?php
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<exchangerates>
    <row>
        <exchangerate ccy="RUR" base_ccy="UAH" buy="0.33291" sale="0.33291"/>
    </row>

    <row>
        <exchangerate ccy="EUR" base_ccy="UAH" buy="18.60253" sale="18.60253"/>
    </row>

    <row>
        <exchangerate ccy="USD" base_ccy="UAH" buy="14.97306" sale="14.97306"/>
    </row>
</exchangerates>
XML;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just feed the necessary url and use `simplexml_load_file()` of you want to use the url:

```
$url = 'https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?exchange&coursid=3';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach($xml->row[0]->exchangerate->attributes() as $key => $exchangerate) {
    if($key == 'buy' || $key == 'sale') {
        $exchangerate = 10 * (float) $exchangerate;
    }
    echo '<div id="attribute_'.$key.'"></div>','<div id="valuta">'.$exchangerate.'</div><br/>';
}
```

Comment: it`s works, but how make cycle, to take all info in url and make code like <div id="currency">RUR</div><div id="currency_2">UAH</div><div id="currency_2">0.32239</div>...?

Comment: @BiDbMAK just add a div like creating it on a string: `echo "<div id='$key'>$exchangerate</div><br/>";`

Comment: yes I just make it, echo '<div id="attribute_',$key,'"></div>','<div id="valuta">',$exchangerate,'</div>',"\n";

Comment: And nowwww))) I can start next step, it`s must be like 0.32239 * 10 = 3.2239  and how to make this I realy don`t know(

Comment: @BiDbMAK just create an if inside the loop: `if(is_numeric($exchangerate)){ $exchangerate *= 10;  }`

Comment: I don`t understand, it`s i must create some like for ?

Comment: @BiDbMAK check my revision to see what i mean

Comment: how i can check your revision? I am new user in stackoverflow

Comment: oh) I`m stupid) ok all works) thank you very much!) Finally left make $exchangerate = 10 * (float) $exchangerate; when we click on button.. but I think I must make this himself, because you help very much

Comment: @BiDbMAK yes of course since its for another question, and i think you can manage that :) im glad this helped, by the way, if this is resolved, kindly read this one http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0):

what about download the xml before loading

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents("https://www.unicreditbank.cz/web/exchange_rates_xml.php");
?>
```

like this

```
<?php

$string = file_get_contents("https://www.unicreditbank.cz/web/exchange_rates_xml.php");

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($xml->row->exchangerate[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
} 
?>
```